# Error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 24 at Práctica_1.main(Práctica_1.java:27)

Tags: java

Hola a todos comencé a estudiar el lenguaje de Java hace una semana y me puse a resolver un ejercicio qué me encontré donde pedian hacer un programa que almacenar información de un alumno.
Entre eso, pedian qué almacenase las 25 notas de las 25 asignatura del alumno por lo que para eso cree dos arreglo uno de tipo String para guardar las asignaturas y uno de tipo double para guardar las notas y un ciclo for para introducir los datos a estos arreglo, pero cuando se introduce el nombre de la asignatura número 25 en la terminal se pone:
Error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 24 at Práctica_1.main(Práctica_1.java:27) rompiendo el programa, sin dejar introducir la nota en el otro arreglo, ni que se siga ejecutando el resto del programa...
E buscado en youtube y otros lado haber si encontraba alguna solución a esto pero nada... Espero aquí poder encontrar alguna solución... [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: por favor mira [ask] y de paso hace el [tour]. Y el codigo? las imagenes no son codigo que podamos probar....

Answer (score 0):

Estás poniendo que la longitud de tu arreglo sea de **24**.

Creo que estás un poco confundido.

`String[] Assign = new String[24]`

Si bien los arreglos empiezan a contar desde el índice `0`. Ese **numero en los corchetes** no indica hasta que indice llegar, indica la dimensión del arreglo, es decir el tamaño

Entonces basta con cambiar a `[25]`ambos arreglos.

String[] Assign = new String[24]
double[] nots = new double[24]

**Recomendaciones**

- El nombre de las variables se recomienda usar un *camelCase*, es decir siempre empezar con minúscula. Solo para las clases usar *CamelCase* Es decir empezar con mayúscula.
- usa `for(int i = 0; i < Asign.length; i++)` en lugar de `for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++)` De esta forma evitas [números mágicos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_m%C3%A1gico_(inform%C3%A1tica)), además de hacer más dinámico tu programa y evitar estos errores.
- Pega el código que estás usando y no solo una imagen, de esta forma es más fácil a nosotros editar o compilar para ayudar.